# Did the Early Church believe that Mary was the spouse of the Holy Spirit?

Tags: early-church, virgin-mary, pneumatology, church-fathers

In Luke 1:34 the blessed virgin Mary is depicted as the spouse of the Holy Spirit, Luke 1:34-35 says:

> Then said Mary unto the angel, How shall this be, seeing I know not
> a man?
>
> And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy Ghost shall come
> upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee:
> therefore also that holy thing which shall be born of thee shall be
> called the Son of God.

Did any of the Early Church believe that Mary was the spouse of the Holy Spirit? This can be between 80-600 AD

Comment: I am unaware of any Patristic writer who expressed this view

Comment: Early Christianity is generally reckoned by church historians to begin with the ministry of Jesus ( c. 27–30) and end with the First Council of Nicaea (325).

Answer (score 4):

[St. Ildephonsus of Toledo](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07649b.htm) (✝667 A.D.) called her the **"*sponsa Spiritus sancti*" ("spouse of the Holy Ghost")** in his [*Libellus de Corona Virginis*](http://pld.chadwyck.com/all/fulltext?action=byid&id=Z700002911) or [*The Little Book on the Crown of the Virgin*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9185).

The Alexandrian (Coptic) Liturgy (Liturgy of St. Mark) also calls her the spouse of the Holy Ghost:

> During Holy Week the following invocation is used morning and night:
>
> > Hail to thee, O spotless Dove, **Spouse of the Holy Spirit**, we pray thee to be mindful of us before thy Son.<sup>1031</sup>

<sup>—"Mary in the Eastern Liturgies" by Cuthbert Gumbinger, O.F.M.Cap., S.T.D., in [*Mariology* (vol. 1)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6494) by Juniper B. Carol, O.F.M.; footnote 1031 references a journal article *Devotion to Our Lady in the Coptic Rite* by Alexander Amba in *Eastern Churches Quarterly*, Vol 7, April-June, 1948 [page 408](https://books.google.com/books?id=_agTAAAAIAAJ&q=%22spouse+of+the+holy+spirit%22)</sup>

---

The term **"*sponsa Christi*" ("spouse of Christ")** is more common, both in reference to Our Lady and to consecrated virgins (see Vizmanos, [*Christian Virgins in the Early Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6496)).

[St. Ephraim the Syrian](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05498a.htm) (306-373) was one of the first to call the Virgin Mother Christ's bride, in [*Hymns on the Nativity* hymn 11](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3703.htm#note370476), where she says:

> For I am Your sister, of the house of David the father of us Both. Again, I am Your Mother because of Your Conception, and Your **Bride** am I because of Your sanctification.

<sup>[*S. P. N. Ephrem Syri operum* vol. 4, p. 327](https://books.google.com/books?id=JAxFAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22Equidem%20sum%20soror%20tua%22&pg=PA84#v=snippet&q=sponsa&f=false): "*Equidem sum soror tua, quo amborum nostrorum proavus est David, et quo te concepi etiam mater, **sponsa** quoque per tuam sanctitatem*", the first early Church father cited in Müller [*Mariologia*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9188) [p. 120](https://archive.org/details/desanctissimadei00jose/page/120/mode/2up)</sup>

Comment: I've just read through the entire Liturgy of St. Mark here https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0718.htm and did not come across the phrase "Spouse of the Holy Spirit.  This is interesting as the website is dedicated to the Immaculate Heart of Mary.

Comment: Also, Early Christianity is generally reckoned by church historians to begin with the ministry of Jesus ( c. 27–30) and end with the First Council of Nicaea (325).  This puts St. Ildephonsus outside the range.

Comment: @MikeBorden It's in its Holy Week liturgy.

Comment: What is the date of origin of the Holy Week liturgy?